# Compiling scala files inside their package folder from Command Line

Tags: scala

I am trying to compile scala files from INSIDE their package folders. 
So I have three files, `Patient.scala`, `PatientMonitor.scala`, and `VitalSigns.scala`, they all reside in the following path `gasguru/patient/`

Here is my file `VitalSigns.scala`

```
// /gasguru/patient/VitalSigns.scala
package gasguru.patient
  class VitalSigns () {
      var heartRate = 0;
  }
```

and I compile it with the following line: `scalac -d ../.. VitalSigns.scala`
this results in the `VitalSigns.class` file being created in the same directory as I am currently in.

Now if I go to compile `Patient.scala` which contains this:

```
// /gasguru/patient/Patient.scala
import gasguru.patient.VitalSigns;
package gasguru.patient {

  class Patient ( val firstName:String, val lastName:String) {
    val vitalSigns = new VitalSigns();
  }
}
```

and if I try and compile it with this following line: `scalac -d ../.. Patient.scala` I get the following error

```
Patient.scala:2: error: VitalSigns is not a member of gasguru.patient
import gasguru.patient.VitalSigns;
       ^
error: error while loading VitalSigns, Missing dependency 'class gasguru.patient.VitalSigns', required by ./VitalSigns.class
Patient.scala:6: error: VitalSigns does not have a constructor
        val vitalSigns = new VitalSigns();  
                                 ^
three errors found
```

Why am I getting this error when the `VitalSigns.class` resides inside of the same directory as where I am compiling the file? Shouldn't importing it suffice?

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
chs@ubuntu:~/GasGuru/gasguru/patient$ ls
exceptions            Patient.scala     VitalSigns.scala
PatientMonitor.scala  VitalSigns.class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing the source file of `VitalSigns.scala` as a parameter, so it will try to search for a classfile. The classfile of a class in the package `x.y` is under the directory `x/y`, which means it is trying to find `gasguru/patient/VitalSigns.class`, which does not exist in the current directory you are at.

If you add `-classpath ../..`, it should find the file.

Comment: SO I guess I am confused, why doesn't compiling VitalSigns.scala put it in the package gasguru.patient? Isn't that what the declaration is saying? I also added the file structure in the OP.

Comment: also, I tried adding -classpath ../.. and I got the following error: `error: error while loading VitalSigns, class file './VitalSigns.class' contains wrong class VitalSigns
Patient.scala:2: warning: imported 'VitalSigns' is permanently hidden by definition of object VitalSigns
import gasguru.patient.VitalSigns;
       ^
one warning found
one error found
`

Comment: @Lilluda5 It does put the class in the correct place -- but you said, with the `-d ../..` parameter, that the base directory for it is `../..`, which is why it ends up in the same directory you are. But `-d` says where to put things, not where to find them.

Comment: Ok, so `-classpath ../..` is used to find the file, what flag can i pass to the compiler while along with `-d` to indicate this is where you can put AND find the file if that makes any sense.

Comment: @Lilluda5 I'm not sure what you are asking. This works fine for me: `scalac -d ../.. -classpath ../.. Patient.scala`

Comment: So if I compile `VitalSigns.scala` from my top-level directory, it is put correctly underneath `/gasguru/patients/`, so this means the classpath is `gasguru/patients`, right? Is there a compiler flag I can pass while compiling VitalSigns.scala along with `-d ../..` to set the classpath to `gasguru/patients`. Hopefully that clarifies what I am trying to say. Thanks for taking the time to help me understand this.

Comment: Daniel, I figured out my problem. I forgot to remove and Import statement from the file, which is why it was not compiling. Everything seems to be working now. Thank you, again!